# What regulations exist for ATC real time RADAR simulator software?

Tags: air-traffic-control, regulations, software, atc-simulator

Does professional ATC RADAR simulator software need to comply to some regulations or requirements in order to be used for real life controller training?

Have ICAO, Eurocontrol, EASA or FAA published any such regulations or requirements in their documents? If so, any reference to a document is appreciated.

Comment: I can't answer the question, but it looks like the FAA has [developed its own software](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/arc/programs/academy/signal/) and even some other countries are using it

Comment: Such regulations do not exist as far a I know (and I am somewhat familiar with radars & simulators). I assume you are looking for regulations related to ATC operational training simulators.

Comment: @DeltaLima I don't know what "ATC operational training simulators" could mean, if it is real life ATCO training simulator then yes, that's what I'm looking for.

For example can someone use London Control (I'm not affiliated to the company in any way), adapt it to the FIR, and say "I am doing proper ATC RADAR training"? Or there is something that could stop them, because that's actually a game?

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis If you are looking for a job in ATC software development (including radar systems), [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/122374/senior-linux-software-engineer-telespazio-vega-deutschland?offset=5&distanceunits=Km&location=darmstadt&range=20&sort=I) (stack-overflow link)

Comment: @DeltaLima I'll do. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So according to EASA, it is the [AMCs/GM for Regulation 2015/340, Part ATCO.OR (Annex III to Decision 2015/10/R)](http://easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/agency-measures-docs-opinions-2013-11-AMC-&-GM-to-Part-ATCO,-Part-ATCO.AR-&-Part-ATCO.OR.pdf) and specifically in `AMC1.ATCO.OR.C015(b)(b)` where is specifies 11 criteria regarding STD standards, among them being accuracy of aircraft performance, voice recognition realism, equipment, data displays, etc:

> STD criteria
>
> If  a  synthetic  training  device  (STD)  is  used  for  training, it should
>   be approved by the competent authority as part of the course approval process 
>   for  any  training  plan.  Training  organisations  should  demonstrate  how  the STD  will  provide  adequate  support  for the  intended training,  in  particular, how  the  STD  will  meet  the  stated  objectives  of  the  practical  training exercises and enable the performance objectives to be assessed to the level determined in the training programme.
>
> This  demonstration  and  the  related  documentation  should  include  the 
>   following relevant criteria:
>
> (1) the  general  environment,  which  should  provide  an  environment  in 
>   which  STD  exercises  may  be  run  without  undue  interference  from unrelated activities;
>
> (2) the STD layout;
>
> (3) the equipment provided;
>
> (4) the  display  presentation,  functionality,  and  updating  of operational information;
>
> (5) data displays, including strip displays, where appropriate;
>
> (6) coordination facilities;
>
> (7) aircraft   performance   characteristics,   including   the   availability   of manoeuvres,   e.g.   holding   or instrumental landing system   (ILS) operation, required for a particular simulation;
>
> (8) the availability of real-time changes during an exercise;
>
> (9) the  processes  by  which  the  training  organisation can be assured that staff associated with the training conducted with the use of an STD are 
>   competent;
>
> (10) the degree of realism of any voice recognition system associated with 
>   the STD;
>
> (11) where  a  simulator  is  an  integral  part  of  an  operational  ATC
>   system, the  processes  by  which  the  training  organisation  is  assured  that interference  between  the  simulated  and  operational  environments  is prevented.
>
> The  extent  to  which  the  STD  achieves  the above criteria  will  be  used  to determine  the  adequacy  of  the  STD  for  the  proposed  use.  As  a  general principle,  the  greater  the  degree  of  replication  of  the  operational  position being  represented  the  greater  the  use  will  be  possible  for  any  particular training.

Comment: Until something better commes up, I mark my own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of specific regulations regarding ATC training simulators.

ATC simulator training is usually done on an exact copy of the real system (same software & hardware). The radar data is provided by flight simulators which are operated by pseudo pilots (also called blip drivers). These are in 'radio contact' with the trainee. One pseudo pilot usually operates multiple aircraft.

The aircraft simulation usually consists of a very basic three degree of freedom point mass model, an aircraft performance model (e.g. BADA) and a rudimentary autopilot. The pseudo pilot translates commands from the Air Traffic Controller into new autopilot settings. The simulator then calculates the flight path resulting from the settings and provides radar data to ATC system.

Comment: DL thanks for the extra information but I am already familiar with the procedure. I did it when I developed [DARSSY](http://darssy.com) :) Question is *who* (if any) verifies correct and accurate implementation? The closest resource I found is `Commission Regulation (EU) 2015/340`. There it says: _The training organisation shall ensure that the synthetic training devices comply with the applicable specifications and requirements appropriate to the task._ Question is what are these "applicable specifications and requirements". I emailed EASA and I hope to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a training provider needs approval from authorities for the full training program offered, and the simulator is only one part of this. The regulation 2015/340 lists areas to consider for the authorities, based on the authorities being competent to judge OK or not in the given context. Thus, a simulator can't get approval as such other than in a context of its use. But it still needs to be approved when it is a part needed for the specific training program.

Like any tool - its qualities can only be validated against its intended use. For example, a hammer can be "authorized" in the context of building a dog house. Not so much when baking bread. Or, a simulator can be great for training tower control, but not so much for ACC. So it's really up to the authorities to approve each case of use. This is the same also for e.g. cars - they are approved for a certain use, and for that only. And similar to operational ATC systems.